# chromium browser integrated newtab page

Tags: browser, chromium, microsoft-edge-chromium

I'm working on rebranding chromium browser, and I'm having some trouble to setup default new tab page to the one remotely hosted, something that new Edge browser is already doing. but without using page redirect so when you open new tab, you'll get page loaded from URL like

`https://ntp.msn.com/edge/ntp?locale=en&title=New%20tab&dsp=1&sp=Bing&startpage=1&PC=U531`

but address bar won't be updated with that URL, it stays empty and ready for search. Does anyone know what are the steps to do this in chromium, what needs to be changed, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: For new tab pages, that's the default behavior for Chromium/Chrome. It won't show the URL for new tab pages, not sure about Edge though cause I don't use it

Comment: it's not just Edge, few other branded browsers made the same, so it's not loading chrome://new-tab-page/ but actual remote URL which is also able to communicate with chrome to get most visited sites etc... I'm just not sure how they set it up to load remote site.